# Reading in file and adding to arraylist outside of Main class

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I am trying to make an object oriented address book, where I randomly generate name, address, phone number, and output it into a CSV file. I have created a lot of the classes to format the names and addresses, but I am struggling with my fileReader class, the goal here is to get the main class to call the fileReader class, read in whichever file I place, and then add it to the right array list. I have tried a few different methods, but they don't seem to be compiling through. I will post my code below, but I am wondering if I am initializing the arrayList for zipcode correctly in the main class. Also, I have been reading some tutorials on fileReading, and it appears that I have asked for the correct parameters, asking for a (String fileName), but when I try to run it, it won't take in the file.

```
package moduleaddress;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class moduleAddress {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Phone phdiff = new Phone("Home", "952.621.2545");
        CityStateZip csz = new CityStateZip("Oak Park", "CA", "91377");
        ArrayList<String> zipCode = new ArrayList(loadCities("C:\\Users\\Jeff\\Documents\\CLU\\CSC 220\\Address\\zip_code_database_new.csv"));

    System.out.println(phdiff.toString());

    Phone ph = new Phone();
    ph.setNumber("805.852.2545");
    ph.setType("Work");

    System.out.println(ph.toString() + " " + csz.toString());
    System.out.println(csz.toString());
    System.out.println(zipCode.toString());
}

}
package moduleaddress;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

final public class AddressGenerator {

CityStateZip[] allCities;

private AddressGenerator() {
}

public void loadCities(String inputFilePath) throws FileNotFoundException{

    File fileInput;
    fileInput = new File(inputFilePath);      // opening up file
    PrintWriter pwOut = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Jeff\\Documents\\CLU\\CSC 220\\Address\\addressBook1.csv"); // set the printwriter 
    Scanner scnrIn = new Scanner(fileInput);  //inistiate scanner

    pwOut.println("NAME, ADDRESS, ZIP CODE, CITY, STATE, PHONE NUMBER");        //Writing out the first line of the address book
    ArrayList<String> zipCode = new ArrayList();
    while (scnrIn.hasNext()) {    // loop through data with .nextLine(), which reads line of text

        zipCode.add(scnrIn.next());
    }
    scnrIn.close();    //close file


    //public String generateState(){
     //   return(this.state[0]);
   // }
}
}
```

I have other classes in this program if you would like me to post them, but these are the two classes that I am struggling with. Everything else up to this point is compiling through correctly.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I realized that the main error was that the loadCities method was void and it can't be due to me needing to return something. Still, with that change, I am having difficulty now of getting the file to be read and then written into the array list. It is compiling through, but not doing what I would like. I realize I don't have the class made for it yet, but the goal is to take in the info from the file and randomly generate zipcodes from the arraylist.